# Best approach to move content between different instances/installations

Tags: importing-exporting

As most of us are, I am involved on a project where we have different environments.
I have created a profile for the initial installation and we are working with Features to maintain all environments with the same Content Types definition, views, rules, ... When we need to do a change, then we recreate the feature and put in the other environment.

Sometimes I have found I can't do a revert of one feature due to existing data, so I feel interesting and needed to have a very strong mechanism to extract, delete and put again into the site created content.

Also, in the case the customer will use the preproduction environment to start using the application, they will want these contents will be placed into the production environment without the need to create them again.

So I am looking for a strong solution to keep all the contents of the site, easy to backup and move between environments.

I have been playing with:
 - node_export
 - node export dependency 
 - field_collection_deploy
 - bulk_copy

But I can't achieve to have a strong copy of the content. One of the content types has Taxonomy references and field collections those are not exported/imported, and at the end of the import I have several Notices as:

```
Notice : Trying to get property of non-object dans field_collection_field_get_entity() (ligne 1679 dans /users/cve00/web/html/sites/all/modules/contrib/field_collection/field_collection.module).
```

Please, I'll appreciate if anybody could point me to the best procedure to accomplish this common need or guide me to do it with these modules if I am missing some operation.

Thanks in advance.

PS.- Even if someone will remove this sentence by editing the post, I feel grateful for your reading :)

Answer (score 0):

After discussion on freenode #drupal, I have had the advice to avoid as much as possible migration or copy-content, so I am going to use a dump from preprod environment to install the production one, what I thought it wasn't the best solution, it seems in this case it will be the simplest and valid.

I'll still appreciate all kind of thoughts of this issue.